# How to align list items to leading margin?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

This must be a dupe, but I've looked at a bunch of "list alignment" questions and I can't find it.

I want the list to align to the left/leading margin, but keep its text aligned when there is more than one line. It's the default behavior in the Pages word processor, for example:

[image]

See how the left side of the numbers are perfectly aligned with the word "Text" above.

Is there a way to do this without manually adding/subtracting a hard-coded amount of body padding to line it up? That will be brittle because it will depend on the font.

If I try it with HTML:

```html
<p>Indented too much.</p>
<ol>
  <li>Bigfoot</li>
  <li>Loch Ness Monster</li>
  <li>Chupacabras</li>    
</ol>

<p>With padding:0, numbers off to the left:</p>
<ol style='padding-left:0'>
  <li>Bigfoot</li>
  <li>Loch Ness Monster</li>
  <li>Chupacabras<br/> Second line</li>    
</ol>

<p>With list-style-position:inside, second line not aligned.</p>
<ol style='list-style-position:inside;padding-left:0'>
  <li>Bigfoot</li>
  <li>Loch Ness Monster</li>
  <li>Chupacabras <br/> Second line</li>    
</ol>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see reference for this, but it seems like margin of  `1em` is correct.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

ol {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <p>Text perfectly aligned</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Bigfoot</li>
    <li>Loch Ness Monster</li>
    <li>Chupacabras<br>second line</li>
  </ol>



  <div style="font-size:24px">
    <p>Text perfectly aligned</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Bigfoot</li>
      <li>Loch Ness Monster</li>
      <li>Chupacabras<br>second line</li>
    </ol>
  </div>


  <div style="font-size:8px">
    <p>Text perfectly aligned</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Bigfoot</li>
      <li>Loch Ness Monster</li>
      <li>Chupacabras<br>second line</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort :) but that is not showing as aligned in my browser. Too bad I can't put a screenshot in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[user agent stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#user-agent_stylesheets) sets **padding-inline-start** (40px in my browser).

It is little tricky - One option to get "perfect left align" is to set [padding-inline-start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start) value - same as the base size of the ol text.

`padding-inline-start` works better for RTL/LTR lists (One value for both VS "padding-left").

```css
ol.big{
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-inline-start: 2rem;
}

ol.small{
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding-inline-start: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h3>Hello</h3>
<ol class="big">
  <li>Bigfoot</li>
  <li>Loch Ness Monster</li>
  <li>Chupacabras</li>   
  <li>Chupacabras</li> 
</ol>
<hr>
<ol class="small">
  <li>Bigfoot</li>
  <li>Loch Ness Monster</li>
  <li>Chupacabras</li>    
</ol>
```

For long lists (>10) it is even more tricky - one idea:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFXVJBzsMCA

Comment: Mmm. It looks lined up in Chrome, but not Safari (I'm on a Mac).